# SQL Alias in where cause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias, where-clause

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT table.column, (select count(table1.column1) from table1
        where table1.column1 = tablecolumn)
        AS exp1, (select count(table1.column3) FROm table1  
        LEfT OUTER JOIN table  On table1.column1 = table.column2   
        WHeRE table.column = table1.column3 AND table1.column1 <= table2.column1 AND table.column = 23206) AS exp2
        FROM table1
        WHERE table1.column1 = something and .......
    ) expVys
    WHERE exp1 >= exp2 ORDER BY table1.name1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a CTE:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
 SELECT  DISTINCT table.column, ((select count(table.column) from table
 where table.column = tablecolumn)) 
     AS exp1, ((select count(table.column3) FROm table  
     LEfT OUTER JOIN table  On table.column = table.column2   WHeRE table.column = table.column3 AND table.column <= column 
     AND table.column = 23206)) AS exp2
     FROM table
)

SELECT * 
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  exp1 >= exp2
```

I don't know if this helps regarding your comment, but you could wrap it all in a SELECT:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT  DISTINCT table.column, ((select count(table.column) from table
 where table.column = tablecolumn)) 
     AS exp1, ((select count(table.column3) FROm table  
     LEfT OUTER JOIN table  On table.column = table.column2   WHeRE table.column = table.column3 AND table.column <= column 
     AND table.column = 23206)) AS exp2
     FROM table
) TableAlias
WHERE exp1 >= exp2
```

Comment: help from jyparask help me, but i need only one huge command for this fix my problem. Because i will using sql command in software where i cant use more command in one value. I can use more selects but every select must be in one main select. Do you understand me what i think?

Comment: its working and now i go trying this sql to software if it will be access.

Comment: in mysql its work but in software dont work because it dont like TableAlias

Invalid select creation. View «0».Template «10647».Filter «0».
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Incorrect syntax near 'expVys'.

Comment: Invalid select creation. View «0».Template «10647».Filter «0».
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Incorrect syntax near 'expVys'.

Your TableAlias = expVys for me

Comment: can you provide the full sql statement you are using?

Comment: I cant public my full sql statement but it is almost same with more parametres. But software dont like TableAlias after select. it still say me that
    Incorrect syntax near 'expVys'. Select:SELECT * as alias_1000 FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT and nexts....

Errors:

 (System.Exception).
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Incorrect syntax near 'expVys'.

Comment: Do you have an `as alias_1000` next to `*` ? remove that.

Comment: i edited my first posts what i have now in sql statement and sorry for formating.

Comment: What is your software?

Comment: helios is my software

Comment: software stil transform our sql to little diferent sql statement which is bad. Horrible.

Comment: Can you give an example of the transformed SQL? Sorry, but i need info to understand what is wrong.